# How do I do 'dpkg-reconfigure -a'?

Tags: package-management, 20.04, dpkg

As a means to fix "Failed To Start Session" at Ubuntu Login I have found [an advice](https://itsfoss.com/failed-to-start-session-ubuntu-14-04/) to run

> `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a`

which supposedly should reconfigure all packages; in a console interface. Alas, on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system `dpkg-reconfigure` does not recognize `-a` or `--all` option.

What is the corresponding command in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Comment: Six years passed. Why do you think your problem is the same? Why do you think the solution is the same? Which desktop environment do you use? What happened before  first occurrence of "Failed To Start Session" ?

Comment: That advice was for Unity, not for Gnome. Lots of the startup system has been reworked since them, `man dpkg-reconfigure` doesn't even have a -a flag anymore. I think you found stale advice.

Comment: Please do not use commands that are from before the previous LTS. So with 20.04 do not use commands from before 18.04. Between LTS we often have big changes like a change in desktop manager en window decorator manager.

Answer (score 2):

The `-a` option was removed 6(!) years ago in the [upstream Debian package](https://salsa.debian.org/pkg-debconf/debconf/-/commit/f0451016661813041d66a100ce03c1298c4ed854). It was never intended as a package system management option. It only purpose was to collect bug report in multible packages.

If this option worked as a fix for your issue, it was certainly not intended. The "[advice](https://itsfoss.com/failed-to-start-session-ubuntu-14-04/)" from FOSS seams more like a sledgehammer for the "failed to start session" issue. In most cases deleting the x-manager files in the user home is suffisant.